# Remove rows from a dataframe where values in two columns dont match in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove the rows from a dataframe where the numbers in columns 'X2' and 'X3' don't match. I want to be left with only the rows with matching values in columns 'X2' and 'X4'.

Here is an example dataset:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(X1 = c("OP2413iiia","OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2645ii_a","OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_b","OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_c","OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_d","OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_d"),
                         X2 = c("3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","4","3","3","3","4","2","3","3","3","4","2","4","3","3","3","4","2","4","2","3","3","3","4","2","4","2"),
                        X3 = c("OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2413iiic","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a"),
                        X4 = c("3","3","3","4","4","4","2","2","2","2","4","4","4","4","4","2","2","2","2","2","2","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","3","3","3","3","3","3","3"),
                         value = c("1.610613e+00","1.609732e+00","8.829263e-04","1.080257e+01","1.111006e+01","1.110978e+01","4.048302e+00","5.610458e+00","5.609584e+00","9.911490e+00","1.078518e+01","1.133728e+01","1.133686e+01","1.738092e+00","9.247411e+00","5.170646e+00","6.074909e+00","6.074287e+00","6.212711e+00","3.769029e+00","5.793390e+00","1.124045e+01","1.163326e+01","1.163293e+01","7.752766e-01","1.008434e+01","1.222854e+00","6.469443e+00","1.610828e+00","1.784774e+00","1.784235e+00","9.434803e+00","4.512563e+00","9.582847e+00","4.309312e+00"))
```

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: Try wtih `subset` i.e.  `subset(dataframe, (as.character(X2) != as.character(X3)) & (as.character(X2) == as.character(X4)))`

Comment: @akrun works like a dream. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use two expressions connected with `&` in `subset` from `base R`.  As all the columns are `factor` class (created with default settings of `data.frame` i.e. `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`), it is better to convert to `character` class with `as.character` (or make use of `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the `data.frame`)

```
subset(dataframe, (as.character(X2) != as.character(X3)) & 
          (as.character(X2) == as.character(X4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> where the numbers in columns 'X2' and 'X3' don't match

Based on your example, I presumed you wanted to write X2 and X4.